How to manage AccessibilityFocusState for SwiftUI accessibility keyboard
I am trying to learn how to programmatically control the accessibility focus in SwiftUI apps.
I learned about AccessibilityFocusState, and setting up an AccessibilityFocusState for a group of views that contains an enum.
I have written a sample project that has an enum with a few cases for text fields and a button. In an .onAppear() handler for the view, I try to set the current value of my AccessibilityFocusState, currentA11yFocus. I can set currentA11yFocus = .field1, for example, but if I then interrogate the value stored in currentA11yFocus, it's still nil.
If I turn on VoiceOver, THAT works. I am able to change the accessibility focus by changing my currentA11yFocus AccessibilityFocusState variable. I have a "Switch a11y focus" button on my view, and when I trigger it in VO, it switches a11y (accessibility) focus to one of the text fields in my enum. However, with VoiceOver off, it doesn't work.
(There are a class of adaptive devices that interface with iOS apps via a Bluetooth keyboard interface, and you can test their accessibility by using any Bluetooth keyboard. That's what I'm using to test that feature.)
The docs make reference to setting up AccessibilityFocusState  for different AccessibilityTechnologies, but only list 2 choices, .voiceOver and .switchControl. I've tried specifying one, both, or neither. No joy.
I would expect there to be an option for keyboard technologies, but there's not. Is there something I'm missing?
Here is the bulk of the code from the project:
enum CurrentA11yFocus: Int, Hashable, CaseIterable {
    case button
    case field1
    case field2
    case field3
    static func randomElement() -> AllCases.Element {
        return Self.allCases.randomElement()!
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appObject: AppObject
    @AccessibilityFocusState var currentA11yFocus: CurrentA11yFocus?
//    @AccessibilityFocusState(for: [.switchControl, .voiceOver]) var currentA11yFocus: CurrentA11yFocus?

    @State var string1: String = "String 1"
    @State var string2: String = "String 2"
    @State var string3: String = "String 3"
    var focusString: String {
        return currentA11yFocus.map { String(describing:$0) } ?? "NIL"
    }
    
    var array = Array(1...5)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Main header")
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 100)
                ProductDetailsHeaderView()
            }
            Button("Switch a11y focus") {
                appObject.message = "A11y button tapped."
                
                print("button tapped")
                print("old currentA11yFocus was \(focusString)")
                //
                //
                //
                if currentA11yFocus == nil {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05){
                        currentA11yFocus = .field1
                        print("currentA11yFocus set to \(focusString)")
                    }
                } else{
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05){
                        currentA11yFocus = CurrentA11yFocus(rawValue: Int.random(in: 1...3))
                        print("----> Set a11y focus to random value \(focusString) <----")
                    }
                }
            }
            .accessibilityFocused($currentA11yFocus, equals: .button)
            
            TextField("Field 1", text: $string1)
                .accessibilityFocused($currentA11yFocus, equals: .field1)
                .border(.gray)
            TextField("Field 2", text: $string2)
                .accessibilityFocused($currentA11yFocus, equals: .field2)
                .border(.gray)
            TextField("Field 3", text: $string3)
                .accessibilityFocused($currentA11yFocus, equals: .field3)
                .border(.gray)
            
        }
        .padding(5.0)
        .onChange(of: currentA11yFocus) {
            print("In OnChange. changed currentA11yFocus to \(focusString)")
        }
        .onAppear() {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05){
                currentA11yFocus = .field2
                print("In .onAppear(), Set currentA11yFocus to \(focusString)")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        Spacer()
        Text(appObject.message)
    }
}

And here is a link to the full project on Github.

Anyone? @BenzyNeez? I'm at a loss here. (sorry for the direct ping, but you seem to know a lot about SwiffUI. I can make UIKit sit up and dance, but am still learning my way around SwiftUI.)
